# File.createTempFile throws Permission denied

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i want to make file for saving image with jpg format

```
 public static File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    final String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    final String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timestamp;
    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
    storageDir.mkdirs();
    return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
}
```

above is my function to create file and located in a class named FileHelper, and this is example code when im using that function

```
 if (filePath == null) {
     File photoFile = null;
     try {
        photoFile = FileHelper.createImageFile();
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     filePath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();

     BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     options.inSampleSize = 2;
     try {
        bmp = getBitmap(filePath);
     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        bmp = BitmapHelper.reduceResolution(filePath, widthPixels, heightPixels);
     }
  }
```

it works in some devices and it also throws error in some of devices, and the error is:

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2018)
    at com.mogawe.mosurvei.util.FileHelper.createImageFile(FileHelper.java:671)
```

is there anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: did you take storage permission ?

Comment: What is your targetSdkVersion and in which device API you are running this app? (Because in Oreo, I am able to get filePath using sme code)

Comment: @NaitikSoni my targetSdkVersion is 29 and minSdkVersion is 23

Comment: @JyotishBiswas i have done it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ve found solution for my own problem >_<, So the solution was [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage). If you target Android 10 (API level 29) or higher, set the value of `requestLegacyExternalStorage` to `true` in your app's manifest file:

```
<manifest ... >
<!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting
     Android 10 or higher. -->
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

hope this can help who has the same problem, thanks!